# Build passes locally but fails on Travis

Tags: python, django, docker, travis-ci

I'm going through a Django course right now (recorded online), and we use Travis. I've notices that my builds on Travis fail, even though they pass locally.

I've tried to look at different files provided by the instructor an compare it to my code but I can't find any difference. Honestly, this is all very fresh to me so I don't really know even where I should be looking, or what part of the code I should be pasting here for the question.

This is the end of the Travis build log:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "db" (172.18.0.2) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
The command "docker-compose run app sh -c "python manage.py test && flake8"" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

And this is my repo:
https://github.com/Tsabary/recipe-app-api

Comment: Is that the way the course told you to use postgres? It's a rather odd setup to me ... I don't see you actually have a postfgres db instance running. There's a pg docker container you could pull down for this

Comment: IN fact - this scenario is even covered in the docker docs! I sugegst you follow their approach ... https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Comment: @urbanespaceman Yes everything I've done so far is from following the course. I'll take a look thank you@

Comment: Trying to install postgres in your own containers is just unnecessary hassle, when they provide an official image that does it all for you :) Good luck!